# Highcharts polar graph data not being displayed on the graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[error on data display img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO8jx.png)
[image]
This is my code for the JS. I am getting the data as it is displayed in the image(blue bar all the way to the left). The data is all the way over to the left and I am not sure why. I do not apply any special css to this graph. The html is just a div with the id to render the graph to. What am I missing here? :(

**CSS** (in browser)

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
rect[Attributes Style] {
    x: 0;
    y: 0;
    width: 1854;
    height: 400;
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
user agent stylesheet
* {
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
}
Inherited from svg
Style Attribute {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
Inherited from body.ng-scope
html, body {
    /* -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* line-height: 1.42857143; */
    /* color: #333; */
    /* background-color: #fff; */
}
Inherited from html
button, select, html, textarea, input {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
html, body {
    /* -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**JS**

```
    //graph
        var irbTable ={
                chart: {
                    renderTo:'irbGraph',
                     inverted: false,
                      polar: true,
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Top 20 Notifications'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                },
                subtitle:{
                    text:"<br>Top 20 Assignee's with the most Notifications"
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'column',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [],
                     showInLegend: false
                }]
        }


        $http.get('../irbTop20.json').success( function(data){
            var processedTop20 = new Array();
            $.map(data, function(obj,i) {
                processedTop20.push({name: obj.assignee, y: parseInt(obj.totalNotifications)});
            });                     
            irbTable.series[0].data = processedTop20;

            var AssigneeChart = new Highcharts.Chart(irbTable);
        }).error(function(data,status){console.log("Error status : "+ status)});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  Are you saying the labels are too far to the left?  Can you get this minimal example to show the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/ghxqf9yx/1/

Comment: instead of the data radiating from the center it is all the way over to the left. the labels are fine. I can't get it to show the problem because I have no idea why it is happening :(

Comment: console.log the irbTable.series[0].data array after it is set.  Also inspect the element in the web inspector to see what styles are applied to it

Comment: the data is being filled as I want it to. The name as the person's name and the y as the totalNotifications. And I updated the question with the css from the browser.